# Possible to build Jekyll site into two dist folders based on YAML front matter?

Tags: jekyll

So I have this site, lets call it `example.com`, that has had multiple languages; English and Swedish. Up to this point we’ve served the Swedish version on `example.com/sv/{pages-in-swedish}` and the English pages and posts on `example.com/{pages-in-english}`.

Now we’ve decided to move the Swedish version to `example.se` and serve only the English pages on the `.com` domain.

Preferably I don’t want to have two parallel repos with duplicate sets of JS and CSS (since they’re identical) but rather based on a YAML front matter tag (`language: en` vs `language: sv`) spit out two different dist folders (for example `dist/` and `dist-sv/`) during build.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not out of the bow. But you can write a plugin for that http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: OK, thanks @DavidJacquel! Unfortually my Ruby skills are non non existent..

Answer (score 0):

There is still no standard for internationalization with Jekyll but I can point you to this [useful discussion on Jekyll talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/multi-language-strategies-with-jekyll/315) on how to manage I18n.